# Cannot scrape Lithuanian language characters from the web

Tags: c#, encoding, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have created a simple web scraper in C# using HtmlAgilityPack. I am scraping a Lithuanian website and the content on the website has Lithuanian characters (ąėęįųūčšž). When I scrape the content, instead of these Lithuanian characters I get ???. For example, if the word is Aušrinė, I get Au?rin?.

I have tried to add headers to my httpClient trying to make it accept ISO-8859-4 characters:

```
var url = "http://www3.lrs.lt/pls/inter/w5_sale_new.balsp_bals_id=-28555";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-4");
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

//Console.WriteLine(html.Result);

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
```

It doesn't work. I am still getting question marks instead of ąėęįųūčšž. Does anybody know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Read the bytes, then get the string from the bytes with the correct encoding

Comment: How are you viewing the results?  It may just be the viewer you are using.

Comment: For now, I am viewing the results from console. But while debugging I can see that the scraped content is stored in variables without these characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! It works and displays Lithuanian characters correctly if I get my html like this:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1257");
var html = web.Load(url);
```

In the meta tag of the web page that I am scraping I have found that it supports charset=windows-1257.